# Closed-form for rational power sum

Tags: summation

$$s_n = \sum_{k=1}^n e^{1/k}$$

This sum came up while practicing closed-form finding on a calculus book's infinite series chapters.

Using Concrete Mathematics' perturbation method, I arrive at

$$s_n + e^{1/k+1} = e + \sum_{k=1}^n e^{1/k+1}$$

Which I can't seem to rewrite with a constant in front of the sigma. I noticed a lot of the sums have rational powers with the index in the denominator. **In general, is there a way to solve these rational sums**?

Comment: Well, there is no nice analytic representation of your sum.  That is obvious. So what do you want? If $k$ is a large number, then $exp(1/k)$ is close to $1$. You could expand the exponential as $1 + 1/k+ ....$.

Comment: I wondered if there was a closed-form for the partial sums. You say it's "obvious" that none exists; could you say why? (of course the sum diverges, but that doesn't mean there isn't a nice expression for it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no **known** closed forms for sums of the form $\displaystyle\sum_na^{n^b}$, for $a\not\in\big\{0,\pm1\big\}$ and $b\not\in\big\{0,1,2\big\}$ In our case, $a=e$, and $b=-1$.