# How do I evaluate this sum :$\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{n^3}$ and Is there a visual proof for it?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, visualization

if $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n = \frac1{1-z}, \quad z \in \mathbb{C},\; |z| < 1 .$$

then is there a way to deduce this sum:$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{n^3}$$ from the

above Identitie or any visual proof if it was existed  ?

Note: $z$ is a complex variable

Thank you for any help

Comment: I'd sort of assume the answer is "no" - I doubt there is a closed form. The [theta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function#Jacobi_theta_function) can handle the case of summing $z^{n^2}$ - but it is itself a special function, and is little better than just treating the series abstractly, and evaluating numerically. The closed form for summing $z^n$ can be found with generating functions, but that approach will only yield answers for algebraic functions. I can't prove the latter sum isn't algebraic, but it seems very unlikely.

Comment: many mathematicians used the above geometric serie, but what about the second at a least a visual proof .?

Comment: but theta function can't handle the case of z^n^3

Comment: See [my answer to this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1326449).